# What is causing my POST request to fail (CORS with Express/Angular)?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors

At this point, I feel like I've tried everything I can think of and that has been searched.

[image: CORS Not Succeeding, FireFox Quantum Console]

The "pure" version of my code is as follows:

**Server.js - Express**

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('./DB');
    businessRoute = require('../routes/business.route');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true}).then(
    () => { console.log('Database is connected') },
    err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database'+ err) }
);

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
businessRoute.all('*', cors());
app.use('/business', businessRoute);


let port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const server = app.listen(function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

**business.route.js - Express, concat.**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const businessRoutes = express.Router();

// Require Business model in our routes module
let Business = require('../models/Business');


// Defined store route
businessRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res) {
    let business = new Business(req.body);
    business.save()
        .then(business => {
            res.status(200).json({'business': 'business added successfully'});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
        });
});
```

**business.server.ts - Angular**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BusinessService {
  uri = 'http://localhost:4000/business';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addBusiness(person_name, business_name, business_gst_number): void {
    const obj = {
      person_name: person_name,
      business_name: business_name,
      business_gst_number: business_gst_number
    };
    console.log(obj);
    this.http.post(`${this.uri}/add`, obj).subscribe(
      res => console.log('Done')
    );
  }
}
```

**What has been Tried**

I've attempted to use the following code, which has been recommended on numerous sites, including SO:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

I've attempted to remove the cors module for the code, using the attempted solution as a replacement. I used the code in the express router. I've so used both the module and the code in conjuction in both the server.js and router, as well as (and what is still in the code) `businessRoute.all('*', cors());`

I'm missing something, I have to be. Any help is appreciated.

As requested, here is the network inspector information from Chrome:

[image: Chrome Network Inspector]

And it did give me an OPTIONS error:

[image: Options Failure]

Comment: Can you try in chrome? You might get a more explicit error message. And can you post a screenshot of the network instpector, showing the response for the OPTIONS request?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the delay:

`OPTIONS http://localhost:4000/business/add net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is what Chrome shows. The network inspector will be posted in a moment.

Comment: Looks like you cannot even get a response from the API for the OPTIONS request. Just checking, does the API work with GET requests?

Comment: I set up the `businessRoutes.route('/').get()` with `res.json({'message': 'Testing'});`. I sent the request through Postman as a GET request for `http://localhost:4000/business/` and recieved "Could not get any response".

Comment: `app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.json({'message': 'Test'}) });` in **server.js** and sent the request through Postman as `http://localhost:4000/` and also recieved no response.

Comment: It's not a cors issue then. What if you try using the machine IP address or 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue, thanks to David. The issue was in:

```
const server = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

I was missing `port` in `app.listen()`.

Thank you for everyone who has helped. I'm inclined to delete the question as it does not have to do with CORS at all, but I was given a warning about deleting questions.

**A Request For The Community**

Editing the question to something like "Why is Express refusing my API requests?" would be a more accurate question, but make the previously posted answers irrelevant. On top of this, Ebin's answer is unique to all the answers I have seen about the CORS issue, and believe it may help others.

For these reasons, I'm leaving it up to the community and how they feel about the question staying, and if they have any suggestions for improving it to make it worth staying.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error then I used this

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    if(req.method ==='OPTION'){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
```

then it was worked, try this

Comment: I used the code on its own and even placed the code in businessRoute.all('*', yourCode) and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `const app = express();` from your `business.route.js`
and `businessRoute.all('*', cors());` from your `server.js`

I'd use `app.use(cors())` before anything else too